# PHP Internals: Difference Between INI Macros

Tags: php, macros, php-internals

I'm working in a C codebase for a PHP extension.  This extension defines several `php.ini` settings.  From what I've seen, there are **two** macros that do this.  They are `PHP_INI_ENTRY_EX` and `STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY_EX`.

```
PHP_INI_BEGIN()
    PHP_INI_ENTRY_EX (...)
    STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY_EX (...)
PHP_INI_END()
```

What's the practical difference between creating a `php.ini` setting with one macro vs. the other?  That is, I can follow the white rabbit down the macro hole and [see the final C that's generated](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_ini.h#L103), but what I want to know is what sort behavior/functionality differences a PHP developer using these `ini` settings will see.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I think the two used are `STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY` and `PHP_INI_ENTRY` https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_12.htm

Comment: Thank you @AbraCadaver -- that doesn't directly answer my question, but there's lots of good/useful information at that link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(the following is my best guess on how all this works -- corrections welcomed in the comments)

The `STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY` and `STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY_EX` macros allow an end-user-programmer to create ini settings whose values are saved in memory  (and, presumably, can be set and fetched via `ini_set`/`ini_get`).  The `PHP_INI_ENTRY` and `PHP_INI_ENTRY_EX` macros allow an end-user-programmer to create ini settings that trigger a callback function once, and then take some action in their own  program/extension (i.e. setting some global-ish state in their program not related to PHP's ini system).

The `_EX` version of the macros take an **ex**tra parameter -- this extra parameter is a callback that PHP will use to display the ini value in places like `phpinfo`.  For example, you cam see [the `ldap.maxlinks` ini definition here with a `display_link_numbers`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/ext/ldap/ldap.c#L141) callback. The source then [defines the `display_link_numbers` callback here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/Zend/zend_ini.c#L596).

The `STD_` macros are designed to work with a specific sort of state object/structs.  Using the above `ldap.maxlinks` example again, the three key parameters are `max_links`, `zend_ldap_globals`, and `ldap_globals`.

```
STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY_EX("ldap.max_links", "-1", PHP_INI_SYSTEM, OnUpdateLong,
    max_links, zend_ldap_globals, ldap_globals,
display_link_numbers)
```

Above, the `zend_ldap_globals` parameters is the name of a struct definition, setup with the the `ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS` and `ZEND_END_MODULE_GLOBALS` macros.  You can see the macro calls [that create the `zend_ldap_globals` definition  here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h#L43).  The above `max_links` parameter is a field on this same struct.

Finally, the `ldap_globals` parameter is an instance of that struct, created via the `PHP_GINIT_FUNCTION` macro.  This macro allows a programmer to setup a "per-php-request" global and (I think) is the memory where PHP will store the ini's value.  You can see the [ldap per-request global setup here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.2/ext/ldap/ldap.c#L147).

When you've setup a struct to hold you ini's state like the above, you can then use a set of predefined PHP callbacks (`OnUpdateLong` above) to have these values automatically set when the PHP user sets a value via `php.ini` (or one of the various other places a PHP `ini` value can be set, depending on which `PHP_INI` constant you've passed to your `STD_` macro (`PHP_INI_SYSTEM` above)).